# An Issue with an AWS EC2 instance WebSocket connection failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

As I tried to run the chat app from localhost connected to MySQL database which had been coded with PHP via WebSocket it was successful.

Also when I tried to run from the PuTTY terminal logged into SSH credentials, it was displaying as Server Started with the port# 8080

```
ubuntu@ec3-193-123-96:/home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/server$ php websocket_server.php
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught React\Socket\ConnectionException: Could not bind to tcp://0.0.0.0:8080: Address already in use in /home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 /home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/IoServer.php(70): React\Socket\Server->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0')
#1 /home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/server/websocket_server.php(121): Ratchet\Server\IoServer::factory(Object(Ratchet\Http\HttpServer), 8080)
#2 {main}
thrown in /home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php on line 29
ubuntu@ec3-193-123-96:/home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/server$
```

So I tried to change the port#8080 to port# 8282, it was successful

```
ubuntu@ec3-193-123-96:/home/admin/web/ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/public_html/application/libraries/server$ php websocket_server.php
```

Keeping the shell script running, open a couple of web browser windows, and open a Javascript console or a page with the following Javascript:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://0.0.0.0:8282');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

From the browser console results:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://5.160.195.94:8282/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

**websocket_server.php**

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
   new HttpServer(
     new WsServer(
          new Chat()
    )
   ),
   8282
);
$server->run();
```

**I even tried to assign Public IP and Private IP, but with no good it resulted in the same old result?**

This was the composer files generated after executing and adding src folder `$composer require cboden/ratchet`

**composer.json(On AmazonWebServer)**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.1"
    }
}
```

**composer.json(On localhost)**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.3"
    }
}
```

How am I suppose to resolve/overcome while connecting it from the WebSocket especially from the hosted server with the domain name such as 
http://ec3-193-123-96.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8282');
```

**From the Security Group**

- Under Inbound tab
  [image]
- Under Outbound tab
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to a connectivity issue with an EC2 there are few things you need to check to find the root cause.

- SSH into the EC2 instance that the application is running and make sure you can access it from within the EC2 instance. If it works then its a network related issue that we need to solve.
- If step 1 was successful. You have now identified it is a network issue to solve this you need to check the following.

  - Check if an Internet Gateway is created and attached to your VPC.
  - Next check if your subnets routing table has its default route pointing to the internet gateway. check this [link](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/SecureTransport_54_on_AWS_InstallationGuide_allOS_en_HTML5/page/Content/AWS/securitygroups/st_gateway_subnet_routing.htm) to complete this and the above step.
  - Check your subnets [Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) rules to see if ports are not blocked
  - finally, you would want to check your Instances Security group as you have shown.

If you need access via a EC2 dns you will need to provision your ec2 instance in a [public subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) and assign an [elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

If an issue still exists check if the [EC2 status checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) pass, or try provisioning a new instance.